# Will writing identical data to blocks of a file under ZFS use space in snapshots?

Tags: zfs, snapshot, copy-on-write

I have a 16M file.

I take a snapshot of the ZFS filesystem which contains it.

If I overwrite the file with the same data, will ZFS need to store two copies of all of the blocks of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ZFS will allocate extra space for the same file if a snapshot is taken from the fileset.

First let's create an empty fileset and prepare a file to copy from. For simplicity reasons, *compression* was turned off and the pool was created on a single disk without any *raidz* or *mirror*.

```
[root@localhost ~]# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/testfile bs=16M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
16777216 bytes (17 MB) copied, 0.113345 s, 148 MB/s    


[root@localhost ~]# zpool create tank sdd
[root@localhost ~]# zfs create tank/test
```

The space used on disk can be seen with `zpool list`.

```
[root@localhost]# zpool list tank
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank    9.94G   182K  9.94G         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

---

Now copy the file over to the ZFS fileset, create a snapshot and look at the space used.

```
[root@localhost ~]# /bin/cp /tmp/testfile /tank/test/

[root@localhost ~]# zfs list -t all -r tank/test
NAME        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/test  16.0M  9.61G  16.0M  /tank/test

[root@localhost ~]# zfs snapshot tank/test@1
[root@localhost ~]# zfs list -t all -r tank/test
NAME          USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/test    16.0M  9.61G  16.0M  /tank/test
tank/test@1     0B      -  16.0M  -
```

Okay, copy the same file again to the same location in the ZFS fileset and look at the space used again.

```
[root@localhost ~]# /bin/cp -f /tmp/testfile /tank/test/
[root@localhost ~]# zfs list -t all -r tank/test
NAME          USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/test    32.0M  9.60G  16.0M  /tank/test
tank/test@1  16.0M      -  16.0M  -
```

Also the disk space used in the pool is growing to 32MB.

```
[root@localhost tank]# zpool list tank
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank    9.94G  32.2M  9.91G         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

---

As you can see, the `tank/test` fileset now accounts for 32MB in total, splitting up in 16MB in the `tank/test` fileset and 16MB in the `tank/test@1` snapshot. Also the output of `zpool list` shows an allocation of 32MB on disk.
If you repeat *copy and take snapshot* the `tank/test` total USED would grow further.

#### Update

Thanks @Andrew Henle for asking. Had to update my answer above and will continue the *deduplication* stuff below.

Let's do this again with a fileset that has *deduplication* enabled.

```
[root@localhost]# zfs destroy -r tank/test
[root@localhost]# zfs create tank/test-dedup
[root@localhost]# zfs set dedup=on tank/test-dedup
```

I will skip the single steps here and will just add the output of the overview of the used space.

```
[root@localhost ~]# zfs list -t all -r tank/test-dedup
NAME                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank                 32.3M  9.61G    24K  /tank
tank/test-dedup      32.1M  9.61G  16.0M  /tank/test-dedup
tank/test-dedup@1    16.0M      -  16.0M  -
[root@localhost ~]# zpool list tank
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank    9.94G  16.3M  9.92G         -     0%     0%  2.00x  ONLINE  -
```

With *deduplication* enabled, the snapshot is still reported to use the *extra* size, but as you can see with `zpool list` the *deduplication* is saving the space on disk and gives a deduplication ratio of 2.

IIRC in general it is not recommended to use deduplication due to heavy memory usage and the resulting performance impact. I think there is work going on to improve the deduplication feature in ZFS.

Comment: Is that with or without deduplication enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but (for some versions of OpenZFS, at least) you can avoid this extra allocation of identical blocks using [nop-write](https://openzfs.org/wiki/Features#nop-write)

> ZFS supports end-to-end checksumming of every data block. When a cryptographically secure checksum is being used (and compression is enabled) OpenZFS will compare the checksums of incoming writes to checksum of the existing on-disk data and avoid issuing any write i/o for data that has not changed. This can help performance and snapshot space usage in situations were the same files are regularly overwritten with almost-identical data (e.g. regular full-backups of large random-access files).